# When I use JMockit 1.18 console says method should not have parameters

Tags: maven, junit4, jmockit

I was using **JMockit 1.13** in my maven project. I have passed some arguments to my test case to mock some classes for the test case. Test cases were running fine. But now I updated to **JMockit 1.18**, Now I see error on console when I run test case like this  `method should not have parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates that JMockit was not initialized at the beginning of the test run, so the JUnit integration remained inactive. You will need to move the `jmockit` dependency before `junit` in the test classpath, *or* annotate your test classes with `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`.